# Generalise in Vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to Vba for excel programming(worked in access before) and want help in understanding on how to generalize excel.  I tried a lot of code in Vba from internet and stack overflow, below is where I need help.

How can I copy paste data. I have a main sheet( 20 columns) and daily small sheets having around 5 columns(can be different in each of the small sheets). Now I need to map these sheets in to the parent sheet. 
Eg; I map a file of 50 rows and 5 columns, so in parent sheet 15 columns will be empty for all the 50 rows. For next sheet some other columns will be empty. I am just stuck as how to select a particular columns every time.

```
x.Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
Range("A65536").Select **' What does A65536 mean**
ActiveCell.End(xlUp).Select
lastrow = ActiveCell.Row
Range("A2:A" & lastrow).Copy y.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("a65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
Range("B2:B" & lastrow).Copy y.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("b65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
```

The above code works but not for me because I have blank values too for columns in some rows and therefore the next values occupy these spaces and that is wrong for me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: I think using that intimidating word is highly unrecommended in SO.

Comment: Apparently you know (or you can count) how many columns and rows are included in child sheets. And you know the order of child data in the parent sheet. So you can just count rows and columns using your order and based on that paste values to the parent sheet.

Comment: @JLILIAman: When referring to myself, humorously, I didn't see the problem. I would never refer to anyone besides myself with that term.

Comment: Note : in first line of your code you select your sheet, and with those next three lines you can find last row (i. A65536: for older versions of excel was the last row of column A - In newer versions its very bigger) and then you copy ranges by columns.

Comment: So after I map the first child file( eg 50 rows of data), some columns would be completely empty( in my case it's 15 for the first file).  Now when I try to map the second file, I need the data to start from 51st row, it does start there but the columns which need to have data are blank as the data goes to the first 50 blank columns. Sorry for being so dumb,  but I cannot just present it properly